# jQuery Slider Events Aren't Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

From what I assumed would be a fairly simple piece of slider code, the events simply will not fire off and its driving me crazy. Not sure what I am missing, so any help would be grand.

Troublesome page can be found here... http://ardaneworldwide.com/home2.html

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Ardane Worldwide</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider_entry/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img src="/slider_entry/header-bg.jpg" />
            <div id="unlock-bottom">
                <div id="slide-to-unlock"></div>
                <div id="unlock-slider-wrapper">
                    <div id="unlock-slider">
                        <div id="unlock-handle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/slider_entry/ui.core-1.5.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/slider_entry/ui.slider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/slider_entry/iphone-unlock.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#unlock-slider").slider({
        handle: "#unlock-handle",
        animate: true,
        slide: function(e,ui){
            $("#slide-to-unlock").css("opacity", 1-(parseInt($("#unlock-handle").css("left"))/120));
        },
        stop: function(e,ui){
            if($("#unlock-handle").position().left == 205){
                window.location="index.php";
            }
            else {
                $("#unlock-handle").animate({left: 0}, 200 );
                $("#slide-to-unlock").animate({opacity: 1}, 200 );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: For some reason, the slide and stop events aren't being fired. It looks like you might be using older versions of jquery ui and slider, try updating to the newest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vdxWm/

To get the slide and stop functions to fire, you need to update to a more recent version of jquery ui/slider.

The latest version of slider doesn't allow you to override the handle element, so you can either style against that, or use some code to adjust your custom handle's position as I've done below.

```
$("#unlock-slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    slide: function(e,ui){
        var han = $("#unlock-handle"),
            con = $("#unlock-slider"),
            left = (con.width() - han.width())/con.width() * ui.value + '%';

        han.css('left', left);

        $("#slide-to-unlock").css("opacity", 1-(parseInt($("#unlock-handle").css("left"))/120));
    },
    stop: function(e,ui){
        if($("#unlock-handle").position().left == 205){
            //window.location="index.php";
            console.log('done');
        }
        else {
            $("#unlock-handle").animate({left: 0}, 200 );
            $("#slide-to-unlock").animate({opacity: 1}, 200 );
        }
    }

});
```